# How to skip demo data in Odoo instance

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, openerp-7

I'm using Odoo on ubuntu server, I want to skip the demo data, I tried the following way, but it does'nt help me out.

```
 --without-demo=True
```

Then I deleted the demo xml files in `__openerp__.py` for CRM module, but there is still demo data in customers field.

Is there any other potential way to skip the demo data.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Use this parameter

```
--without-demo=all
```

Take into account that it requires the parameters `-d` (database) and `-i` (modules to install)

Comment: I'm not doing it manually, I'm doing it via command line, kind of automated set up.So when I'm creating the database from postgres, it automatically loads demo data.

Comment: OK, I changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

when you create a new databdon't check ase in 127.0.0.1:8069/web/database/selector
don't check the box " Load demonstration data " [image]

Answer (score 0):

Small modification to your answer works :-)

```
      --without-demo=ALL
```