# How to configure odoo with install demo data

Tags: odoo

I have two modules I need to install, but I need one module to not install demo data. How to do that?

I have tried with config file `without_demo=sale`. But this does not work correctly with other modules. All modules skip demo data too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424888/how-to-skip-demo-data-in-odoo-instance

Answer (score 1):

So one of the two modules you are trying to install is `sale`, but you don't want to install its demo data. Assuming that at the time you created your database you have opted to install demo data, then all modules that have `demo: [...]` in their manifesto file `__openerp__.py` will install their data.

There are three solutions, for now:

1. Remove the `without_demo=sale` in the config file since this is not
   the way you should do this. Then run Odoo with
   `--without-demo={'sale': True}` parameter.
2. You will need to modify the sale module itself and comment out
   `demo: [...]` in its manifesto. Then create the database with demo
   data enabled. (I discourage modifying the Odoo core, it's a bad practice!)
3. Try deleting all demo data for the `sale` module from Odoo itself.

The results may be unexpected because of the relations of the demo data among modules.